# Rails modules as strict namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, module, namespaces

I'm quite new to rails and I'm a bit confused of how modules work here. I have a project structure like this:

```
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord

# lib/external_service/foo.rb
module ExternalService
  class Foo

# lib/external_service/bar.rb
module ExternalService
  class Bar
    attribute :foo, Foo # not the model
```

I have worked with many coding languages before and I expected it to be easily possible to use 'Foo' inside Bar and ExternalService just like that but

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Foo, expected lib/external_service/foo.rb to define it

The ExternalService::Foo should normally not even be visible outside of ExternalService but the whole project dies on this thing

Am I just missing a kinda 'strict mode'-notation or anything to make sure that I obviously mean ExternalService::Foo inside the service and prevent the service from killing my model?

I know I can just prepend the module but i wanna keep the code readable.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this question has nothing to do with ruby itself, it’s a weird and flaky rails autoloading who breaks everything up.

Comment: oh really? I thought modules is part of ruby itself maybe, thanks for your comment @mudasobwa, im gonna remove the ruby tag

Comment: Modules are part of Ruby. Autoloading of files is done by Rails.

Comment: Modules are indeed ruby. But there is _no autoloading_ in ruby at all. One must `require` necessary files explicitly, as one does `#include` in [tag:c].

Comment: @mudasobwa there's [`autoload`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload)

Comment: Read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms). Basically, your `lib/models/foo.rb` defines a top constant `Foo`. In another file, `class Foo` will need to decide whether `Foo` is a known class to reopen, or a new class to define, and it does the wrong thing. However, you don't post enough details (exact code and file structure) to reproduce your problem with confidence; though if you google for your error message, there'll be a fair amount of hits.

Comment: Do you have a file `lib/external_services/foo.rb` or is `Foo` defined in `lib/external_services.rb` along with `ExternalServices`? Furthermore, could you show the code that causes the error, please? Does it occur within `ExternalServices` (in regard to the nested `Foo`) or when trying to access the top-level `Foo` model in some other part of your application?

Answer (score 0):

so you are using rails 4

if you want to create a module, first you need to import or autoload your lib folder

for example in *application.rb* you can add lib folder to autoload:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

after that because you are using rails you should create a folder hierarchy with snake cased name of your module hierarchy 
for example if you have:

```
module ExternalService
  class Foo
    ...
  end
end
```

your foo.rb file should be in a folder with name 'external_service'

```
{{project_root}}/lib/external_service/foo.rb
```

folder hierarchy is convention of rails.

Comment: Oh I found that line in application.rb and deleted it. Now it isn't throwing looking for the model in the lib anymore, dunno yet if the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Ruby behaves just like this and it's totally ok.

In this case the Foo-Model is already loaded, so ruby prefers this instead of the local one. Also alphabetically app/ is before lib/

A not so beautiful but quick fix is just to call it like this:

```
attribute :foo, ExternalService::Foo
```